# SQL WHERE both values of a variable exist

Tags: sql, select

Suppose that I have a table of global box office information including columns "filmName", "country" and "earnings". The question is how to find out the films that sell better in country A than in country B. Here is my answer:

```
SELECT filmName 
FROM Boxoffice 
WHERE (SELECT earnings FROM Boxoffice WHERE country = "A") > 
(SELECT earnings FROM Boxoffice WHERE country = "B") 
GROUP BY filmName
```

But then I found out that there are some films that are not shown in both countries. I wonder how I can add the condition to the films that are shown in both countries to my existed answer. And I also have no idea if my answer has any problem since I do not have the real data.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should tag SQL requests always with the DBMS in question. Sometimes it is even necessary to know the version. String literals should be inclosed in *single* quotes by the way. The main problem with your query is that the subqueries are not correlated, i.e. they don't  look for the film of your main query. (And the `GROUP BY` in the main query looks strange, as you don't apply any aggregate function. We would rather use `SELECT DISTINCT` in that case. And the database would be better with a separate film table.)

Comment: As to "since I do not have the real data": It is easy to set up some test data and try it. I am using dbfiddle.uk for this. It will be great, if you do this next time. It will help you check your own query and it will help us checking ours. Here is your data with our queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=decc4f732f482481c3bf766b1dbb34ff

Answer (score 1):

I think a self join would be simpler:

```sql
SELECT a.filmname
FROM   boxoffice a
JOIN   boxoffice b ON a.country = 'A' AND b.country = 'B' AND a.earnings > b.earnings;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `filmname` and `country` is the unique key for your table, i.e. there is one row per film and country.

One way to get films that sell better in country A than B is to aggregate and compare the earnings in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select filmname 
from boxoffice 
group by filmname
having max(case when country = 'A' then earnings end) >
       max(case when country = 'B' then earnings end)
order by filmname;
```

Another way is to join, e.g.:

```
select a.filmname
from (select * from boxoffice where country = 'A') a
join (select * from boxoffice where country = 'B') b
  on a.filmname = b.filmname and a.earnings > b.earnings
order by a.filmname;
```